# stop postback from code behind using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have a button and I want to stop post back whenever someone clicks on that button.

I don't want to use return false like this

```
  <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="Unnamed1_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:return false;" />
```

I want to stop it from code behind.

I want to create a div and some content inside the div , so when ever someone click on that button another div will be created with it's contents, but the problem is when I click the button and a post back happen , it remove the first div and construct the second one and so on

Comment: I'm with Parouuu.  Why are you trying to stop a postback?

Comment: If you want to use a button that reacts only on client side how about using a simple html button with an input tag? <input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" />

Comment: This is a case of the XY Problem.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378.  You have a problem you want to solve (from comments, appears to be creating a second div), but instead of asking how to solve your problem, you came up with a solution (stopping postback) and are asking how to do that.  If you post some example code of your entire problem, we can help solve it, rather than trying to solve your solution, which isn't a normal case.

Comment: @Claies, I already solve it, Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do is to disable your button after a user click on them it also disable the postback behaviour and prevent future postback, in this way

```
protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    YourButton.Enabled = false;
}
```